# Aruch Hashulchan's moon-distance estimate

Tags: shiurim-measurements, astronomy, mathematics, aruch-hashulchan

*Aruch Hashulchan* (1829–1908), *Orach Chayim* 397:1, says that a מיל is the same as a Russian верста ([*verst*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verst)) or 500 сажен ([*sazhen*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sazhen)), which comes to 1066.8 meters. In 426:2, he says the distance to the moon is about 43,000 פרסה. A פרסה is four מיל, so 43,000 פרסה come to about 183,500,000 meters.

In fact, though, the distance is about 384,400,000 meters (as had been known, at least approximately, [for millenia](http://galileoandeinstein.physics.virginia.edu/lectures/gkastr1.html) by his day), which according to the *Aruch Hashulchan* is 384,400,000÷4267.2 פרסה, or about 90,000 פרסה.

His estimate of 43,000 is off by a scale factor of 2! What gives?

Comment: Doesn't he also seem to say that the moon is bigger than Mercury?

Comment: @DoubleAA, yes. (Well, as big or bigger.) I don't know what the state of the science was in his days about that. If you do and are bothered, by all means [ask](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). `:-)`

Comment: @msh210 My point was I don't know if he's trying to be accurate or just to quote some old statement (midrash? rambam?) from before it was known precisely.

Comment: @DoubleAA re "I don't know if he's trying to be accurate or just to quote some old statement": the latter may well be true, and evidence of such a statement would make a great answer.

Comment: Even if had been estimated before, it doesn't mean people knew about it in Eastern Europe. (Columbus would have never tried to sail to India if he knew the Earth was as large as Eratosthenes had calculated.)

Comment: @ArielK, I thought of that. I strongly suspect Lithuania circa 1900 still knew the approximate distance of the moon, but any evidence you can provide that there was a group of people at that time who thought the moon was some half as far as we now think it is would make a good answer.

Comment: Anyone have contact info for [R' Alex Schutz](http://www.chareidi.org/archives5759/veschan/oschutz.htm)? He may have considered this question at some point.

Comment: Some people obviously knew more astronomy in Lithuania, but it a long time even for geocentrism to be abandoned. E.g. see http://www.rationalistjudaism.com/2012/06/rabbinic-responses-to-transit-of-venus.html and http://www.amazon.com/New-Heavens-Earth-Reception-Copernican/dp/0199754799

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might simply have been a confusion of units.  [Sizes.com claims](http://www.sizes.com/units/verst.htm) that a Russian *verst* is equal to 500 sazheni, but a Moscovy *verst* is 1000 *sazheni*.  The *sazhen* was fixed at 7 English feet (2.134m) in both systems way back during the 1700s in Peter the Great's rule.

In 397:1, the Aruch HaShulchan says that specifically, he is talking about the Russian *verst* (and therefore, in order to eliminate confusion and to inform *heimisch* readers how long the official *verst* is), he says 500 *sazheni*.

This perspective makes the end of 397:1 much clearer and less redundant:

> ואלפים אמה הוא מיל, ולפי **מדת מדינתינו רוסיא** היא **פרסה רוסית** שקורין ווייארסט, **שהם חמשה מאות סאזנעס**. **וכל סאזען** הוא ד' אמות שבגמרא, כמו שבארנו בחושן משפט סימן רי"ח.

My translation:

> And two thousand *amot* is a *mil*, and according to the **laws of our country, Russia**, that is a "**Russian *parasa***" which is called "*verst*", which are 500 *sazheni*.  And **all *sazheni*** [i.e., Russian, Moscovy, *Litovskaia*] are 4 *amot* in the *gemara*, as we explained in Choshen Mishpat, siman 218.

When he talks about the distance to the moon, he says:

> מ"ג אלף פרסה
>
> 43,000 *parasa*

We have an ambiguity there.  He might be talking about the Russian "*parasa*" (2000 *amot*), the Moscovy "*parasa*" (4000 *amot*), or the Talmudic *parasa* (8000 *amot*).  But all of these definitions are off.  Even the Talmudic *parasa* would be, as @msh210 said:

> 43000 * 8000 *amot* = 43000 * 2000 *sazheni* = 43000 * 14000 ft. = 183,500 km

Perhaps, the Aruch HaShulchan heard that the moon is ~180,000 *versts* away.  The speaker was speaking in Moscovy *versts*:

> = 180,000 * 1000 *sazheni* = 180,000 * 213.4 m = 385,000 km

... but the Aruch HaShulchan understood 180,000 Russian *versts*

> = 180,000 * 500 *sazheni* = 180,000 * 2000 *amot* = 180,000 *mil* = **45,000** Talmudic *parasa*

...which is just about right.  Turns out, the moon's distance from the earth goes [from around 363,000km to 405,000km](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=distance%20to%20the%20moon), so we have some wiggle room.

Comment: Interesting idea. What language does he use regarding the measurement to the moon?

Comment: @DoubleAA "_אינה רחוקה מן הארץ רק בערך _מ"ג אלף פרסה"

Comment: (re your last comment.) Maybe so, but then _haikar chaser min ha_ answer.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, yes, I think the math works out that way. All we need to do now is find a Russian publication that expresses the distance to the Moon in Moscovy versts, preferably one that doesn't specify.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Good luck with that :) You'd also need to show that the AhS saw this publication.

Comment: Such as [this one](http://epizodsspace.no-ip.org/bibl/fant/lyakide/v-okeane-zvezd/lyakide-v-okeane-1892.pdf)? (Will work on this more later. Gotta go.)

Comment: @IsaacMoses Based on pg 103 and Google translate, it looks like that says that Mimas is 151 kilo-*versts* from Saturn.  Mimas is actually ~185km from Saturn, which means clearly it's Russian *versts*.... or way off.

Comment: Actually, more googling seems to yield (not super-strong) evidence *against* this hypothesis. [`"180000 верст" Луна`](http://www.google.com/search?q="180000+верст"+Луна) (= `"180000 versts" moon`) yields only the PDF I linked above, and I don't think the measurement there is referring to the distance to the moon. [`"360000 верст" Луна`](http://www.google.com/search?q="360000+верст"+Луна) yields 8 results including multiple references to books from the 1800s that *do* seem to be telling us the distance to the moon (noting the appearance of apparent conjugations of "расстояние" = "distance").

Comment: ... So we have evidence of Russian literature in the 1800s that refers to the distance to the moon in terms of Russian versts, but none (through this admittedly imperfect method) of such literature that refers to it in terms of Moscovy versts. Note that I am relying on Google Translate for all of the Russian I'm using here.

Comment: @IsaacMoses What makes you think that the Aruch HaShulchan was only looking at sforim for his understanding?  Maybe he spoke to a scholar?  But presumably the scholar would speak in the scholarly language, which your findings imply was Russian versts...

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, my Google analyis applies to the hypothesis that he had consulted literature in Russian that is now searchable by google, which would primarily include secular scholarly texts, I think. Anyway, I noted that this approach is limited.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I wonder what if any Yiddish astronomical texts were out there.